# How to stop background scrolling when viewing modal form on ios 8+ and Safari

Tags: ios, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form in a Bootstrap 3.3.2 modal.
I encounter an issue when viewing it on iOS 8 & Safari only.
This issue does not occur in Chrome or iOS 7 & Safari.

View my js bin here, http://jsbin.com/fokucu/4

After clicking "List Me", then try selecting a drop down or enter text to bring up the keyboard. After it appears, the background will scroll and you cannot scroll down the modal.

It should be noted that if the length of the table has an impact if you can scroll the modal or not without the background scrolling. Essentially more than 10 rows and you cannot scroll the modal after interacting with the form.

I cannot figure out how to solve the problem, plus I thought this was fixed in current version of Bootstrap.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Looks like this is caused by a bug in Mobile Safari. You can follow the open issue on Github [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14975).

Comment: Hey were you able to solve it  ?

Comment: Yes. I solved it using the [workaround here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9023#issuecomment-27701089). What is happening is [explained here](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/bootstrap-3-modals-and-the-ios-virtual-keyboard/). However, I found that this only happens with latest iOS devices so I put in more logic to only look for iOS and then dive in to the workaround I linked above.